# C# UseVisualStyleBackColor

Tags: c#

Is there a way in which I can change the button color and preserve the Windows VisualStyle? I want to create a button that looks like checkBox2 (color and style)
 
[image]

```
this.button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.GradientActiveCaption;
this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;  //if true, BackColor gets ignored
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, not really.  This kind of button background is drawn by VisualStyleRenderer.DrawBackground().  Which in turns pinvokes DrawThemeBackground().  These methods don't take a color.  None is needed because the color is already specified in the theme.

Simulating the appearance with a LinearGradientBrush is your only real hope.  Note that custom drawing a button is quite difficult, all the code is internal and no owner-draw is provided.

Consider using an image.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Passant